# LocalDateTime mapped to Oracle DATE, but not to H2 DATE

Tags: oracle, hibernate, h2, liquibase

Let's say I have JPA `@Embeddable`:

```
@Embeddable
public class SpecificationValidity {    
    @Column(name = "VALID_FROM", nullable = false)
    private final LocalDateTime validFrom;

    @Column(name = "VALID_TO")
    private final LocalDateTime validTo;
}
```

SQL table contains columns `VALID_FROM` and `VALID_TO` and is declared using liquibase changeset as follows:

```
<column name="VALID_FROM" type="date">
    <constraints nullable="false"/>
</column>
<column name="VALID_TO" type="date"/>
```

When I run this code against Oracle database, everything works.

When I run it against H2 database, `Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: wrong column type encountered in column [valid_from] in table [specification]; found [date (Types#DATE)], but expecting [timestamp (Types#TIMESTAMP)]`

Why is it?

Is it possible to have consistent mapping for both dbms?

Comment: What version of hibernate are u using?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you use Hibernate(from your exception message). Since you are using java 8 or above, you might need to add this to your dependency for **hibernate 5.0.x**.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-java8 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.7.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

This helps to convert to and fro from Java 8 types to JPA known types. In this case it allows `LocalDateTime` `LocalDate` and `Instant` etc.,

I'm putting out the mapping that comes along(referred in the article as well).

[image: Java8 type to jdbc type mapping]

A reference article : [Hibernate + java 8 datetime](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-5-date-and-time/)

P.S : For Hibernate 5.2x and above no need for this explicit dependency. 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#basic-datetime

Comment: It's not the answer I'm looking for. In my case I have `LocalDateTime` in java class what I want to keep. `DATE` in Oracle contains also seconds, so that's the reason why `LocalDateTime` is working mapping, even though in a table above, `TIMESTAMP` is used. The question is whether it is possible to have something similar in H2 as well.

Comment: What hibernate version are you using?